# Recover Telegram media (images) after chat deletion

Tags: data-recovery, cache, telegram-messenger

Is it possible to recover lost media (images) from Telegram after the chat/history deletion for both users?
In AppData->Telegram it's stored some cache. Maybe it's possible... Windows desktop.
Sadly on PC Telegram's media files aren't stored unencrypted. In that case after deletion some Recuva-like tool could help.

Comment: Sent a ticket to Telegram. Wondering if they will give a solution ))